# No supported authentication method available when I try to connect to ec2. How to connect to the AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I create ec2-instance on the AWS server:

[image]

Now I try to connect to the server with putty.

- First of all, I downloaded the PPK for instance:

[image]

- In the next I created a connection with putty:

[image]

[image]

- After I launch connection and set the username as *ec2-user*:

[image]

- in the result I got the error:

[image]

---

## How to correctly connect to the ec2 instance with PPK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand from the question is that you did launch an EC2 instance successfully and afterwards you generated a new SSH key pair which does not have any connection to the already created EC2 instance.

What you should have done is to create a new key when the instance was launched:
[image]

OR select an existing key:

[image]

Now, the easiest way to solve this problem is to terminate the EC2 instance and recreate it with your existing key pair. You should be able to chose `wlifter-ppk` from the dropdown.

If, for some reason, you don't want to do this or it is not possible to terminate and relaunch the instance, there are several ways to rescue the instance and attach an existing SSH key.

I. Manually rescue the instance:

1. From Putty [convert](https://superuser.com/questions/405214/using-a-ppk-key-with-ssh) you `.ppk` to RSA public key.
2. Use EC2 Instance Connect or Session Manager to connect to your instance.
3. Locate the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. For Amazon Linux instances this can be found in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh` folder.
4. Open `authorized_keys`, append the new RSA public key and save the file.
5. Connect to the instance using Putty.

II. Use EC2Rescue tool https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-boot-issues/

Comment: Recreate? Do I need to create a new instance? Do I need to create a key for the existing instance and then create another? Why?

Comment: Why is AWS so ugly?

Comment: @Valentyn Hruzytskyi
Not necessarily, for this case probably it would be the easier solution the terminate and launch a new instance. As I said, there are ways to rescue the instance, but they are cumbersome. For real life production situation you would want to go through those steps, for learning purposes it would be waste of time.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new key (.pem file) with a new instance, converted it to .ppk and everything works fine. I probably forgot where my previous pem file was downloaded .... anyway - it's weird and very wrong when I download a PPK file from an instance and can't connect with it. This is the most stupid thing I could expect from aws....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have local Windows and you'd like to connect to your EC2 AWS linux VM.

1. Use PuTTYgen to generate SSH-2 RSA key, 2048 bits.
2. Save keys into file, ie. myaws1.pub and myaws1.
3. In AWS dashboard, find your live instance, open up shell. It'll open up in the browser.
4. You will be logged in most likely as ec2-user
5. vi .ssh/authorized_keys
6. On your Windows, open up myaws1.pub file. take the relevant part and make it one line. Yes, it's broken up into multiple lines. Now press CTRL-C. And over in the browser where you Linux shell, press ESC-I (for insert), now CTRL-V (paste). Save and exit vi.
7. Back to Amazon Dashboard, in Network Security -> Security Groups, create SSH inbound rule with source 0.0.0.0/0
8. Now, when connecting to your instance from Putty use "Auth" in options.

This is what your new line in auth file should look like. I shortened it

ssh-rsa AAAAB3......... aws1